# Explanation of .SQLiteConstraintException: tabtest.id may not be NULL

Tags: android

Can someone please explain for me the below question. this is the below table creation note that id is `null`

```
   db.execSQL(
              "create table tabtest " +
              "(id integer null, name text, timage blob )"
              );
```

if the id is null , ill have an error in the below statment

```
 contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
```

Erorr

```
05-28 22:03:10.826: E/SQLiteDatabase(1861): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: tabtest.id may not be NULL (code 19)
```

why the id should be not null for the parsetInt ?

this the below method.. if you need anything else please ask me.

```
     public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
         List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
         // Select All Query
         String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tabtest ORDER BY name";

         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         db.execSQL("drop table tabtest");
         db.execSQL(
                  "create table tabtest " +
                  "(id integer not null, name text, timage blob )"
                  );
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
         // looping through all rows and adding to list
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
         Contact contact = new Contact();
         contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
         contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
         contact.setImage(cursor.getBlob(2));
         // Adding contact to list
         System.out.println (contact);
         contactList.add(contact);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }

db.close();
// return contact list
return contactList;

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)) states:

> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column
>   value is null or the column type is not a string type is
>   implementation-defined.

To be sure, check if the value of that specific column is null manually:

```
if (cursor.isNull(0)) {
    contact.setID(null);
} else {
    contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
}
```

Comment: If I added the condition it will work normal right ?  ... so as I undestand the getstring should always have values ?

Comment: @Moudiz actually you should be using `getInt()` as the type is an integer you still need the manual `null` check though.